# The active question page shows 0 ongoing bounties when in fact there is one

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

I just noticed that the active question page shows 0 on-going bounties, but there actually is an on-going one:

[image]

If you click on the "featured" tab, it shows the number correctly:

[image]

I guess this is a bug.

<sup>I wasn't sure how to tag this.. so this will have to do</sup>

Comment: Well this suddenly stopped happening.. I'll see if it crops up again.. Might have been a site caching error.

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215792/heisenbug-alert-featured-tab-is-sometimes-borked

Comment: @Undo Yep, guess so. You can't close across sites though :P

Comment: Nope. So it's fine here too ;)

Comment: For performance reasons, these pages are cached for a short while, so on occasion you can get this discrepancy.

Comment: @Oded Which does raise the question how the count can ever get cached with a `0`, but as active. That doesn't seem like intended behaviour.